# Ruby/Rails ActiveRecord JSONb column: How to query for if a list of keys contain any value in a list of values?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create an active record query that considers a jsonb column in a model.

My query currently:

```
ExampleModel.
where("jsonb_column_name -> 'Example key 1' ?| array[:example_values]", example_values: [1,2,3])
```

This query currently looks at the jsonb column in ExampleModel where the key is "Example key 1" and checks if it's corresponding value is contained within `example_values`.

What I **need** is to change 'Example key 1' to a *list* of potential keys that checks against `example_values` and returns all instances of ExampleModel that match.

Are there any SQL/ActiveRecord experts out there that know the syntax of how to do this?

Comment: The way you're attempting to pass the array won't work. What will actually get passed to the array constructor is the text `'[1,2,3]'`. If you want to pass an array the you want to either use *n* number of placeholders - (`placeholders = Array.new(values.length, '?').join(',')`) and then interpolate them into the query `where("jsonb_column_name -> 'Example key 1' ?| array[#{placeholders}]", *values)`. Or you would have to do something like passing a JSON string and using the database specific functions to convert JSON into arrays.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that ActiveRecord does not actually handle querying JSON/Array/Hstore so any solution will be DB specific. I'm assuming this is postgres but you should add that information to the question as well.